# Build specific library from Boost C++ Library

Tags: c++, linux, boost, build, static-libraries

I built the **boost** library in order to use the boost functions **split and format**.

I noticed that the split placed under the algorithm directory, but there is no library named 'algorithm' when I run `--show-libraries` to get the list of libraries.

When I built the whole boost, I didn't find which lib file to add to my project (I don't want to add the all the libs and headers).

**How can I build this specific library?**

Comment: I don't think you need to build anything from that library, it's probably header only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both boost::algorithm and boost::format are header only, so no need to build.
You will find both header files inside the include/boost/ folder:

- include/boost/algorithm/algorithm.hpp
- include/boost/format.hpp

Answer (score 1):

When running **bootstrap** with **--show-libraries**:

> The Boost libraries requiring separate building and installation are:

The algorithm library isn't listed and is even template for the STL equivalent -> header-only.